# Script in Jenkins file giving exit code 1

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get a line from a file in my workspace. I am using this script :

```
        stage('Test') {
          steps {
            script {
              outputJenkins = 'output-jenkins.log'
              sh "cd invoker && mvn clean install && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=\"com.JenkinsRunner\" -Dexec.args=\"qal ${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\" > ../${outputJenkins}"
              logFile = readFile(outputJenkins)
              echo logFile
              adminRepoLogLine = sh "echo logFile | grep \"Admin repo url is :::\""
              echo adminRepoLogLine
            }
          }
        }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
+ echo logFile
+ grep Admin repo url is :::
script returned exit code 1
```

The script works fine in my shell when I try it locally. Are there any contains around doing it in a JenkinsFile?

Answer (score 1):

If we apply various fixes and improvements to the code in the question to achieve the desired functionality, then it will succeed:

```
stage('Test') {
  steps {
    script {
      dir('invoker') {
        sh(label: 'Maven Clean Install', script: 'mvn clean install')
        // assign maven output to variable
        String output = sh(label: 'Maven Git Log', script: "mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=\"com.JenkinsRunner\" -Dexec.args=\"qal ${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\"", returnStdout: true)
      }
      // assign regex return to variable
      def adminRepoLogLine = output =~ /(.*Admin repo url is :::.*)/
      // print extracted string from return
      print adminRepoLogLine[0][1]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `GIT_COMMIT_HASH` is neither an intrinsic Jenkins environment variable, nor defined in the pipeline code in the question, so it will need to be defined at Pipeline scope elsewhere in your code.

Comment: as I recall, `GIT_COMMIT_HASH` is injected into the environment by the Git SCM plugin during checkout.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the *string literal* `logFile` does not contain the string `Admin repo url is :::`. If there's no such match, then `grep` will exit with status `1`.

You probably want to use

```
cat logFile | grep \"Admin repo url is :::\"
```

instead, or, even simpler:

```
grep \"Admin repo url is :::\" logFile
```

Append `|| true` (or `||:`) to the command if you want to avoid the errors when the log line does not appear.

Comment: `||:` is even better than `|| true`, as the latter is a bash-ism (`:` is POSIX)

Comment: Thanks for the hint -- I didn't know that one. Added it as an alternative option (as it's less readable for newbies I suppose : )